# How to use the button on a LCD instead of 'except keyboard interrupt'?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Im trying to get wifite (https://github.com/derv82/wifite) working on my 16x2 Adafruit LCD (http://www.adafruit.com/product/1110).
But for some Reason, if I press the specified button nothing happens.

I want to replace all pieces of code that look like this:

```
try
    ....
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ....
```

With the code for the LCD Buttons:

```
try
    ....
except lcd.buttonPressed(lcd.SELECT):
    ....
```

But for some reason nothing happens if I press the button, I don't get a error - And wifite just keeps doing it's thin.
Any Idea why this isn't working how it should ? 
Or is there maybe a better way ?

Comment: Unless `buttonPressed` returns an exception-type object, I don't think you can do this. I think you want `if lcd.buttonPressed(lcd.SELECT):`. But of course you can't pair a `try` with an `if`, so it's not an easy find/replace job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out `except KeyboardInterrupt ...` is a special construct in Python ... because a [Ctrl]-[C] is handled by your terminal driver and presents an "Interrupt" signal to your program (SIGINT under Unix, Linux and similar operating systems).  (There is similar handling under Microsoft operating systems, with different details and slightly different terminology; but the Python code works the same either way.

There are other ways of accessing various other forms of hardware event ... and the Python `exception` module is not a typical way for those to be implemented.

In the case of the AdaFruit, or other Rasberry Pi devices, you'd use the modules they include with their package.  You've already seen it, and presumably done the required `import` in your code (based on your reference to `lcd.buttonPressed()`).  The problem is that this isn't how you use that function at all.

Read this carefully: https://blog.soton.ac.uk/pi/modules-available/adafruit-rgb-lcd-display/

... it includes example which show how you should be using it.  That should be something like:

```
#!python
# Set up stuff here ...
got_event = False
while not got_event:
    if lcd.buttonPressed(lcd.SELECT)
        got_event = True
        break
    # Do other stuff, perhaps
    # Or time.sleep(0.1)?
if got_event:
    # In case we had other exit conditions from doing other stuff?
    subprocess.call(YOUR_OTHER_PROGRAM)
```

Of course their code is a complete running program.  I'm only highlighting a couple of points here.  You need to loop around until you get the event your looking for (or loop around forever processing these events for as long as your device is up).

The `lcd.buttonPressed()` method is checking to see if the button has been pressed since the last time it was cleared; but the method/function doesn't block ... it returns `True` or `False` (or possibly `None` --- that wouldn't affect these code examples --- any "false" value means the button has not been pressed).

You want to sleep for some amount of time between checks.  They use a half second delay in their example; I used a tenth of a second.  (People will typically perceive a response within a tenth of a second from a computerized device as "instantaneous" while a half second delay will, typically, be slightly annoying).  Checking as fast as you can will just needlessly heat up the electronics.  Even a 0.01 (one hundredth of a second) sleep is sufficient ... but 0.05-0.1 are probably the best practice for something like this.

Comment: Thank you, yes I needed to realize that I can't take the easy way and just use the except and try structure with the LCD. So I needed to write a big loop, needed a bit time but works now as I want it. Thanks for the very detailed answer man.

Comment: Using `try:`... `except ...:` blocks in Python is generally not "the easy way."  Exception handling should be used for handling exceptional conditions and normal flow control should be preferred for code handling the normal flow through your program.  This guideline will generally make your code easier for others to read and maintain.

Comment: I know that it is in general not "the easy way". But if I have a finished script using the try and except blocks - It would be easier to use one of my buttons to replace just the `Keyboardinterrupt` in the script.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want  to have one of the buttons on the Adafruit LCD panel interrupt the program at almost any stage. (It would have been great if you'd mentioned this yourself!)

`KeyboardInterrupt` is a signal sent to a process, usually when a user presses `Ctrl + c` on a keyboard. To be more precise, a signal is sent by the OS and caught by the Python runtime, which raises a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

However, `Ctrl + c` is special! In almost any other case, when a user presses a key or a button, this is not translated into a special signal.

I'm not sure how you could get the behavior you want; this may depend quite a bit on the operating system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is event detection try something like this. You might have to get familiar with `Tkinter`

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback_end(event)
   # do whatever ending procedure you want here 
   quit()

def main()
     # do everything in your main code here
     if lcd.buttonPressed(lcd.SELECT):
          callback_end("<End>")
     root.after(Period,main)

root.bind("<End>",callback_end) # if you press the end key it will call the callback_end function
root.after(Period,main) # repeats main every Period in miliseconds
root.mainloop()
```

I realize that this is not a complete answer but I hope it gets you going in the right direction

Comment: `root.after(100, main)` will only call `main()` once. To have it called repreatedly, `main()` should schedule another call to itself, e.g. by having another `root.after(100, main)` call at its end.

Comment: @taleinat You are right. and the post has been edited, thank you